# How to submit data to flask while using two buttons in a HTML form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to implement a web application that takes in user data to do something and then shows a new page when the task is done. While the task is being executed(since what I am doing takes a while), I am using jQuery to show to the user that it is being performed in the background and he/she needs to wait.

A part of the Javascript works fine and shows the wait screen, but the form data is not being sent to my backend that is running on flask on python.

My HTML file `login.html`:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">  
    
    <title>Connect page</title>

    <!-- Self written CSS  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
  </head>


<body>
  <div class="container"  id="main">
    <div class="alert" role="alert">
      <h4 class="alert-heading">Enter login details</h4>
    </div>

    <form action="#" method="post" id="form_data">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>fieldx</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="abc" name="fieldx" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>fieldy</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="xyz" name="fieldy" />
      </div>
    
      <div class="three_buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="btn_identifier_login" value="do_a" id="ida">Do a</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="btn_identifier_login" value="do_b" id="idb">Do b</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- only this to be shown when "Do a" is clicked  -->
  <div class="container hide-before-click" id="sub">
    <div class="alert" role="alert">
      <h4 class="alert-heading">Please wait while we do a...</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- only this to be shown when "Do b" is clicked  -->
  <div class="container hide-before-click" id="search_page">
    <div class="alert" role="alert">
      <h4 class="alert-heading">Please wait while we do b...</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var ida = document.getElementById("ida");
    var sub = document.getElementById("sub");
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    var idb = document.getElementById('idb');
    var form_data = document.getElementById("form_data");
    var search_page = document.getElementById("search_page");

    ida.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    main.classList.add("hide-before-click");
    sub.classList.remove("hide-before-click");
    form_data.submit();
    e.preventDefault();
    });

    idb.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    main.classList.add('hide-before-click');
    search_page.classList.remove('hide-before-click');
    form_data.submit();
    e.preventDefault();
    });
    
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The python webapp using flask:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, url_for, request, session, send_file
import time
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "a key"

@app.route("/", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        val = request.form.get("btn_identifier_login")
        print(f"{val} is the value recieved from the button") # this is so i can debus and see what is actually recieved.
        #Sadly, this always reads 'None is the value recieved from the button'
        fieldx = request.form.get("fieldx")
        session["fieldx"] = fieldx
        fieldy = request.form.get("fieldy")
        session["fieldy"] = fieldy
        if val == 'do_a':
            time.sleep(3)# actual implementation does something complicated that takes about 3-4 seconds (during which JS shows the please wait text for a)
            return "a done"
        elif val == 'do_b':
            time.sleep(3) # actual implementation does something complicated that takes about 3-4 seconds (during which JS shows the please wait text for b)
            return "b done"
        else:
            time.sleep(1) # this is only here for debugging
            return "didnt understand button value"
    else:
        return render_template("login.html") # this is the main login page

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The css file just in case:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600');

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    background: #FFFAFA
}

.alert{
    background: #a9a9a9 
}


.container {
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .8em 1.2em;
}

.container2 {
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .8em 1.2em;
}

.three_buttons {
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}


.hide-before-click {
    display: none;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
    padding: .8em 1.2em;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.spinner-border {
    text-align: center;
}

.submit_button {
    width: calc(100% - 3em);
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.form-group {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Note: This is the first time I am doing any webapp related stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally solved my problem. Hope it helps future newbies.

Changes were only made to the `login.html` file.

The `div` with the buttons was changed to this:

```
<div class="three_buttons">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="btn_identifier_login" value="do_a" id="ida">Do a</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="btn_identifier_login" value="do_b" id="idb">Do b</button>
</div>
```

and the Javascript was changed to the following:

```
<script>
    var ida = document.getElementById("ida");
    var sub = document.getElementById("sub");
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    var idb = document.getElementById("idb");
    var form_data = document.getElementById("form_data");
    var search = document.getElementById("search");

    ida.addEventListener("click", changedisp_sub);
    idb.addEventListener("click", changedisp_search);

    function changedisp_sub() {
      main.classList.add("hide-before-click");
      sub.classList.remove("hide-before-click");  
      }

    function changedisp_search() {
      main.classList.add("hide-before-click");
      search.classList.remove("hide-before-click");  
      }
    
</script>
```

works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `val = request.form["btn_identifier_login"]`. This should take in the input data to your variable `val`.

Comment: This sadly doesn't seem to work. As soon as I try with this, it says: Bad Request